# How to tell TypeScript that the type of object[foo] is a subset of all the possible object.prop types

Tags: typescript, types

For example, imagine I have this interface

```
interface Measurement {
  date: Date
  width: number
  height: number
  depth: number
  comment: string
}
```

Then I have the following code

```
// these are the strings representing those values
const measurement: Measurement = {}

const fields = ['date', 'width', 'height', 'depth', 'comment']
fields.forEach(field => {
  // Here I do a bunch of processing and after all that processing I know
  // for a fact that `field` can only be one of width | height | depth,
  // and therefore `measurement[field]` will take a number, for sure.

  measurement[field] = 6 // ಥ﹏ಥ
  // !! Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date & number & string'
})
```

So I guess the question is, how do I tell TS that in spite of `measurement[field]` having the type `Date | number | string`, I know it's going to have the type `number` and it shouldn't complain when I do `measurement[field] = 6`.

Maybe I'm just looking at this with the wrong approach. If that's the case, what should I be doing instead?

Thanks!

Comment: The specifics of the "bunch of processing" is relevant to whether or not the compiler can determine, like you did, that `field` can only be `"width" | "height" | "depth"`. You'll either need to change that processing to let the compiler know what's happening, or do something equivalent to a type assertion.  Could you try to turn the code in this question into a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem so that others can make a concrete suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the type inferred for `fields` will be `string[]`, which is not specific enough for the compiler to do the sort of control flow analysis you want to see here.  One easy way to change this is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler to infer the narrowest type it can:

```
const fields = ['date', 'width', 'height', 'depth', 'comment'] as const;
// const fields: readonly ["date", "width", "height", "depth", "comment"]
```

You can see now that `fields` is known to be a read-only tuple of specific [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types).

Then, inside your `forEach()` callback, `field` will be known as a union of those string literal types.  If you use type guards to eliminate the `"comment"` and `"date"` possibilities, the compiler will narrow the type of `field` even further until it knows that you can assign a `number` to `measurement[field]`, as desired:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
    //  field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment"
    if (field === "comment") return;
    if (field === "date") return;
    // field: "width" | "height" | "depth"
    measurement[field] = 6; // okay
})
```

If the processing you do to eliminate `"comment"` and `"date"` is too complicated for the compiler to understand, then it will not narrow and you'll get the error you mention:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
    //  field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment"
    if (field === "COMMENT".toLowerCase()) return;
    if (field.split("").reverse().join() === "etad") return;
    // field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment"
    measurement[field] = 6; // error!
    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
})
```

In this case, you'll need to either use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent to tell the compiler that what you are doing is safe.  For example:

```
function assert(x: any): asserts x {
    if (!x) throw new Error("BAD ASSERTION");
}

fields.forEach(field => {
    //  field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment"
    if (field === "COMMENT".toLowerCase()) return;
    if (field.split("").reverse().join() === "etad") return;
    // field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment";
    assert(field !== "comment" && field !== "date");
    // field: "width" | "height" | "depth"
    measurement[field] = 6; // okay
})
```

Here we are using an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) named `assert()` to tell the compiler what's going on.  The implementation of `assert()` throws an error but in fact I could have left it out.  Or, possibly more straightforwardly:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
    //  field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment"
    if (field === "COMMENT".toLowerCase()) return;
    if (field.split("").reverse().join() === "etad") return;
    // field: "date" | "width" | "height" | "depth" | "comment";
    measurement[field as "width" | "height" | "depth"] = 6; // okay
})
```

where we use a type assertion directly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITgZwK5QgWwnGQG8AoZS5AEzkgC5kAROiCqgd2GrAAtGQ2fACNo7SrwjAA5rzAChoqOJoQADnwUixVZAgD2+QuEaYwUUNLIBfMmQMgzyQllwEiYZAF5S15FjQMHDxjMABuOwcnGGAIABtqTG9kAG0AclpINIAaZDSuHl4cvMkZOWKM9T4KgyMPNIBdfySo8LIAena9fUdPGPjExjw4ah64gE9UgCJMiCncqYK+eeQp0tkwFZmq3i3a0KmGu36EzAA6GH0oAFFEXgAKE+pvAD5SFU7KJ8YZ1inkAA+qyWu0Bq3Wcn+QO2GlB0P2HimKmAMGQj1iCW8Xh8UwR4CmAEpkHgwLgQBFdCi0U8sTjZoTiRBSVByR8ut9gdxlmC1lINlDVtQdkjdC5gu5wCknk0fAA2CLWAnHDGJC5XW4IB40rxvci6T7IDm-SACxZcuHgvmQnlC2GmvGbZGo9EDWmrADCAHlUKhrgA5AAqUzOYH0ABl9BxoO6sBB7gSiSSyRSqFSXQkzpg1HFgGB7lNCWc8AA3aCYOMEs4AK30oHjbqmTJGDKTLJTlE+RvpPJBpohmxtwp5DpFVDFblCUpVMuQ8uQn2gUCuAEI2cgA+M1Cg0oJtFA0shgEkQPpPFhMDIQHBhHEUKHkGBN9uQBBS-uzjYlWQYNgQAgwMAPTNOWUB5gAHowcAgOMBKQZgIFgEkYHvJSzrLmBRJ8EuHDIC+OHXFAS5QPmABCACCTDIGRADK1HXAASgGACSnp+oSCrKgM5yXDcdzps8OooVQBpdn8Pbmn2VoDtCtrcvChgHE61Iqg2Xo+v6QYhuGkbRrG8aJkyyZKfxmbZrm+aFiWZYVtWtYgPW2I4k21AtoZbZrqJJriYUkllNJgpDvJdT4u2wHQHmNLLtiqwjsgABkcWGipUV0n8BKhZ2Ko-L2PL9qasm7Co44hB4U4DDOc6fPoADWcDjJ+nGnGqvGavxrxCR2XRJQMPzdtCOXQnlg52sOCmIsZ2rRVMam+oGwahhGUZQDG5b6YyzKsqhykDKZOZ5gWlZWVAq2VjWdZEo5qzOa5G0ZeyWWCmJ-USblUn5YFMVjSFRVBBOpU0gEZo+a9fnvXaFVhPOXQ1XVDVkEAA)

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do is type it.

```
interface Measurement {
  date: Date
  width: number
  height: number
  depth: number
  comment: string
}

const measurement: Measurement = {}

const fields = ['date', 'width', 'height', 'depth', 'comment'];

fields.forEach(field => {
  // processing
  measurement[field] = 6 as Date & number & string;
})
```

Comment: This does remove the error, but is making `6` a union type instead of telling TS that at that point I only expect `measurement[field]` to be of type number, which was my goal. Thanks for your answer though! I'm sure I'll use that somewhere else in my code